# Showing that $\phi(s,t)=2^s3^t$ is injective

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I am trying to show that the function $\phi(s,t)=2^s3^t$ is injective, where $\phi: \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$.

**My intuition:** For any $w,x,y,z\in\mathbb{N}$, then $\phi(w,x)=\phi(y,z)\implies 2^w3^x=2^y3^z\implies w=y$ and $x=z$ by the unique prime factorisation theorem. Hence $\phi$ is injective.

Is my intuition correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy what is the kernel of this function? Is it empty?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Can $w=x$ or $y=z$? I am having trouble convincing myself of this point.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy But is it necessary to assume that $w\neq x$ and $y\neq z$?

Comment: $w=x$ case is not special. You don't have to assume that

Comment: There is no need to assume that $w \neq x$ and $  y\neq z$.

Comment: @dust05 why is that?

Comment: $2^{x}3^{x}=2^{y}3^{y}$ also implies $x=y$ by the same theorem.

Comment: Why did you want to assume $w = x$? for example, $36 = 2^2 \times 3^2$ has unique factorization, just like $12 = 2^2 \times 3^1$ or $24 = 2^3 \times 3^1$.

Comment: @dust05 Ah, I see. I made a silly mistake. I have updated my response, is this correct?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I have updated my response.

Comment: I think it is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is valid.

Perhaps a clearer way to show this without appealing to unique prime factorisation is as follows:

Suppose
$$2^w3^x = 2^y3^z.$$
If $w \neq y$, then dividing out the smaller power of $2$, the equality becomes $\text{even} = \text{odd}$, a contradiction. So $w = y$, and dividing out $2^w$, we get $3^x = 3^z$, giving $x = z$.

Comment: Aargh, beat me to it! Nicely written.